# What is the name of this tabletop multiplayer card game

Tags: identify-this-game

You start with a normal 52-card deck, you then distribute the cards randomly and evenly to all players. First player starts by putting down any number of cards he wants (provided they are the same number) face down,(for example 2 5's), he then says what he just put down.

All other players can either pass and the turn goes to next player, or say bull$***. If they were correct and that player was putting down cards different than what he was saying, he gets the pile of cards that have been played, if the cards matched what was played, the one saying bull$*** gets all the cards. If it is your turn, and you don't have any cards you want to play you can skip.

The player who finishes the cards in his hand wins, sort of like UNO, but without knowing the real cards.

The strategy is to sneak in the cards that you don't have all 4 suits of without anyone knowing and returning the entire card pile to you.

Some obvious no-no's to better explain:

1. If you don't have all 4 suits of some number in your hand, don't put down a mix of cards and say (4 6's when you don't have the 4 6's)
2. Start your turn by putting any sets of 4 suits you have as there is no way for someone to win a bull$*** on them
3. If someone is about to finish his cards, it can be rewarding to claim bull$*** and bring him back to square one

My friends call it bull$***, what is it's common name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always called it B.S. growing up, but it is also knows as **Cheat**, as well as a couple other names.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheat_(game)):

> Cheat (also known as Bullshit, B.S., Bluff, or I Doubt It[3]) is a card game where the players aim to get rid of all of their cards.[4][5] It is a game of deception, with cards being played face-down and players being permitted to lie about the cards they have played.